# How do I use reactjs with Google DFP/AdSense

Tags: javascript, adsense, reactjs

I'm wanting to build a project with Facebook's reactjs framework (JSX), but given how it renders, how would I use this with Doubleclick for publishers?

If I trigger adsense/urchin, how do I tell React not to change/update those items?

Is there an alternative adwords script/interface I can use?

Comment: Did you implement it ? can you share ?

Comment: @Unenumrated not yet, got redirected with some other things, will probably have this in place by the end of april...  If you see the comment thread on my answer, you can see where it starts...

I may publish my solution as a node/npm module, so it can be re-used more easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple component that handles displaying ads, taking into account [viewability best practices](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/6199883). (Thanks to [Tracker1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43906/tracker1) for the comments here, which helped me tremendously in putting this together.)

```
import React from 'react';
import Waypoint from 'react-waypoint';

let instance = 0;

class Ads extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    id: React.PropTypes.string,
    width: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    height: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    adslot: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  constructor() {
    this.__id = 'ads-instance-' + ++instance;
    this.displayAd = this.displayAd.bind(this);
  }

  get id() {
    return this.props.id || this.__id;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
      // Define the ad slot
      googletag
        .defineSlot(
          this.props.adslot, 
          [this.props.width, this.props.height], 
          this.id
        )
        .addService(googletag.pubads());

      // Start ad fetching
      googletag.enableServices();
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{width:this.props.width, height:this.props.height}}>
        <Waypoint onEnter={this.displayAd} />
        <div id={this.id}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  displayAd() {
    const id = this.id;
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
      googletag.display(id);
    });
  }
}

export default Ads;
```

I've used react-waypoint to ensure proper viewability (not loading ads until users will see them). When the waypoint hits the bottom of the viewport as a user scrolls down to it, displayAd() shows the ad. The offset could be enhanced, but hopefully this will be a good starting point to give you the general idea.

If you have several ad slots on one page, you can use unique IDs in place of `#ad-container`.

Comment: Just a couple suggestions, you may want to wrap it up into an npm-module, even if it's limited usability... also, passing in the slot size/adslot/id via properties, as well as generating a unique id if one isn't specified.

Comment: This is an awesome helpful resource, I was looking through our mobile team's ad integration wondering how on earth it would play nicely with react, this makes so much more sense after seeing it so thanks for taking the time to publish how you achieved it!

Answer (score 7):

(will clean up this answer with a jsx example when I have one, for now...)

Thanks to rcs in freenode #reactjs:

```
rcs> tracker1: componentDidMount and make sure 
you're not throwing it away when you don't mean to

tracker1> rcs: so use componentDidMount for adsense/dfp 
binding, and simply don't change the render output?

rcs> tracker1: Yeah. Your render should write out the 
<ins class="adbygoogle" data-analytics-uacct ..... > 
piece, and you should fire off the adsbygoogle.push in 
componentDidMount

tracker1> cool... didn't think it would be that easy for 
some reason...

rcs> tracker1: Or for dfp, handle the defineAdSlot in CDM, 
and googletag.pubads().refresh() on something that fires 
after they're all written out.

rcs> The thing that will trip you up is if you're firing 
things that make React thing that written node needs to get 
removed and replaced, instead of moved, etc.

rcs> But that shouldn't be a primary worry -- just something 
to keep in the back of your head if you're seeing more 
impressions/ad loads than you should be.

tracker1> they'll only change on a navigation/route change

rcs> Keep in mind that adsense TOS is vague on ajax page loads.
rcs> Or 'client side' page loads.
```

(fix apos)

Comment: I wonder if this is working? I tried to place the code inside componentDidMount but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It seemed to work in my testing, never got the chance to dig further.

Comment: haha gotcha. I still see a blank white box for now and dunno if this is normal or what..

Comment: `<ins className="adsbygoogle"
         style={{display:'inline-block',width:'336px',height:'280px'}}
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-11111111"
         data-ad-slot="11111111"></ins>` in the React component I substituted out the class to className and style to array object to make it a standard React component syntax. But it seems google doesn't know I have put the code on the page though..

Comment: @Shih-MinLee Did you put `googletag.pubads().refresh()` in your `componentDidMount` event handler?  If you're using DFP, you should create a container div, and use `googletag.defineSlot` and `googletag.display`, which was what I did for this.

Comment: ok I think it's working now.  Just adsense doesn't show any ads at the first 2-3 days. thanks!